# Access the except part of before_action in the controller itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action, controllers

So I have a controller, say

```
class RandomActionController < ApplicationController
```

and I have a method `check_authorization` in `ApplicationController` that I use in `RandomActionController` as

```
before_action :check_authorization, except: [:create, :get_actions, ..]
```

Now in another action inside `RandomActionController`, I might be building an array of actions excluding ones in the `except` section of `check_authorization`, or whatever. My problem is, how do I get those actions as a hash/array or any other form?

Comment: put them in a method/constant and use twice. the only way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are passing to the `except` part is a literal array, string or symbol. Rails does not let you (afaik) introspect a controller callback to extract the arguments it was declared with.

If you want to be able to a re-use list of actions it you need to link it to an identifier.

For example this a pattern I often use:

```
class ApplicationController

  private

  def self.member_actions
    [:show, :edit, :destroy, :update]
  end

  def self.collection_actions
    [:new, :index, :create]
  end
end

class FooController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_foo, only: member_actions

  def self.member_actions
    super + [:fuzzle, :wuzzle]
  end 
end
```

But you can just as well use constants or anything else that is available in the class context.